# Remove special characters from string and turn every str into an array item

Tags: javascript

I have the following str, which I want to sanitize by removing the character "/" from it and turning it into an array. The str looks like this one:

```
var str = `“01 Lima /  / ”
“01 Lima / 50 Lima / ”
“01 Lima / 51 Barranca / ”
“01 Lima / 50 Lima / 202 La Molina”
“01 Lima / 50 Lima / 203 San Isidro”
“02 Arequipa /  / ”
“02 Arequipa / 63 Arequipa / ”
“02 Arequipa / 64 Caylloma / ”
“02 Arequipa / 63 Arequipa / 267 Cercado”`
```

My ideal output would look like this:

```
["01 Lima", "01 Lima 50 Lima"] and so on
```

I made the following code which sanitizes the input a bit, but not exactly what I need:

```
const ubigeoParts=str.replace(/""/g,'').split('/');
```

Any ideas on how I could accomplish what I want?

Comment: do you have really `“` as delimiter?

Comment: No, screw up when copying. It´s "/". I´ll correct it!

Comment: Are you asking from a Mac with some sort of automatic "smart quotes" enabled?

Comment: No. That´s just how the input looks (I read it off a txt file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps

In two lines

```
let replaceStr = str.replace(/\“|\”|\/|/g,'').split("\n");
replaceStr = replaceStr.map((elem) => elem.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim());

console.log(replaceStr)
```

In one line

```
let replaceStr = str.replace(/\“|\”|\/|/g,'').split("\n").map((elem) => elem.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim());

console.log(replaceStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most optimized way to do it, but it should get the work done nonetheless

```
str.match(/“(.+)”/g).map(s => s.replace(/“|”|\s*\/\s*/g, ' ').trim())
```

Comment: I get "Error: str.match(...).replace is not a function"

Comment: I had forgotten a bit, my bad !

Comment: This still keeps the "/"

Answer (score 0):

you can use split `\n` to take each line then replace `"/"` with `space`

```js
var str = `“01 Lima /  / ”
“01 Lima / 50 Lima / ”
“01 Lima / 51 Barranca / ”
“01 Lima / 50 Lima / 202 La Molina”
“01 Lima / 50 Lima / 203 San Isidro”
“02 Arequipa /  / ”
“02 Arequipa / 63 Arequipa / ”
“02 Arequipa / 64 Caylloma / ”
“02 Arequipa / 63 Arequipa / 267 Cercado”`


const res = str.split("\n").map(el => el.replace(/\s*\/\s*/g, " "))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Close, but I need the white space after each name (for instance, your output looks like this "“01 Lima50 Lima”", but I need "01 Lima 50 Lima")

Comment: i updated my answer i think it look like what you want except the quotes i can remove them if you want

Comment: Yes! Could you remove the quotes please?